Hibernate 6.0 reverse engineering: cannot change property name
I'm trying to generate POJO's with hbm2java, a reveng.xml file, and a connection to a MySQL 8.0 database.
In the reveng.xml file, I put a column balise with property "toto" on column "status". But when doing the generation, I get the POJO with a "status" attribute instead of a "toto" attribute.
Plz can someone help me ?
Here is the reveng.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table-filter match-name="metier" package="fr.jcb.dao" />
    <table name="metier" catalog="jcb_db" schema="jcb_db"
        class="fr.jcb.dao.Metier">
        <column name="status" property="toto" />
    </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>

And generated class:
package fr.jcb.dao;
// Generated 17 oct. 2024 � 15:11:20 by Hibernate Tools 6.0.0.Final


import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static jakarta.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * Metier generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="metier"
    ,catalog="jcb_db"
    , uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="name") 
)
public class Metier  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer jobId;
     private String name;
     private String status;
     private String description;

    public Metier() {
    }

    
    public Metier(String name, String status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Metier(String name, String status, String description) {
       this.name = name;
       this.status = status;
       this.description = description;
    }
   
     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)

    
    @Column(name="job_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getJobId() {
        return this.jobId;
    }
    
    public void setJobId(Integer jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }

    
    @Column(name="name", unique=true, nullable=false, length=100)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    
    @Column(name="status", nullable=false, length=100)
    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    
    @Column(name="description", length=65535)
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
    
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}

As U can see the property is status and not toto
Using mvn and the plugin:
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/hibernate.properties</propertyFile>
                        <revengFile>src/main/resources/reveng/model.reveng.xml</revengFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.tool</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-tools-orm</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${mysql.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>entity-generation</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <ejb3>true</ejb3>

